# Decide the solution $f$ to the partial different equation $x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I want to decide on the solution $f$ which solves the partial differential equation
$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$
where $f=e^{-2y}$ when $x=1$, and where we introduce $u=xe^{y}$ and $v=xe^{-y}$.

My attempt at a solution:

I have my already included variable substitutions $u=xe^{y}$ and $v=xe^{-y}$. I get

$$f(x,y)=g(xe^{y}).$$

I am having some complications finding the function that also satisfies the condition.

Since $f(x,y)=g(xe^{y})$ then $f(x,0)=g(x)$ Now I feel like I want to put $g(x)=e^{-2y}.$ But I also feel like that might be incorrect.

How should I reason when I am solving this problem?

Comment: Why do you plug in $0$? The initial condition is for $x=1$, not $y=0$

Comment: That is true indeed, thanks for pointing it out, I thought of y=0 instead of x=1 @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo or a mistake in your calculus. The general solution of the PDE is not $f(x,y)=g(xe^y)$ but is :
$$f(x,y)=g(xe^{-y})$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary function.

The function $g$ has to be determined according to the condition $f(1,y)=e^{-2y}$

$f(1,y)=g(e^{-y})=e^{-2y}$

Let $X=e^{-y}\quad;\quad y=-\ln|X|$

$$g(X)=e^{-2y}=e^{-2(-\ln|X|)}=X^2$$
Now the function $g(X)$ is known
$$g(X)=X^2$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=xe^{-y}$
$$f(x,y)=\left(xe^{-y}\right)^2$$
$$\boxed{f(x,y)=x^2e^{-2y}}$$

Comment: I'm not very familiar with pdes but  are there many solns to a given pde?

Comment: @Buraian There is a wealth of literature on uniqueness of PDE solutions. http://www.aessweb.com/pdf-files/jasr-3(8)-786-799.pdf

Comment: I'm not paritcularly interested in studying about PDEs at the moment. I asked because you and I got different solution yet both satisfy the differential equation

Comment: @Buraian In a sense. $g(xe^{-y})$ is *the* general solution, and $g$ can be any $C^1$ function so yes there are many solutions. However your solution $g(xe^y)$ is just plain wrong since it cannot be of the general solution form. So in that sense, there aren't multiple solutions.

Comment: The PDE $xf_x+f_y=0$ has an infinity of solutions on the form $f(x,y)=g(xe^{-y})$ because they are an infinity of functions $g$. But there is only one function $g$ which satisfies the condition $g(1,y)=e^{-2y}$. So there is only one solution for the PDE subjected to the specified condition.

Comment: It is advised to check the general solution found $f(x,y)=g(X)$ with $X=xe^{-y}$. $$f_x=e^{-y}\frac{dg}{dX}\quad \text{and}\quad f_y=-xe^{-y}\frac{dg}{dX}$$ $$xf_x+f_y=xe^{-y}\frac{dg}{dX} -xe^{-y}\frac{dg}{dX}=0$$ Thus $f=g(xe^{-y})$ is solution of the PDE.